# steps to create a web app with backend and database and web

Tags: database-design, uml, documentation, react-fullstack, planning

The plan is to create a new product
Im a full stack developer
The business idea is ready in mind
I created a google drive and Github repos
Multiple juniors might work on the project
I still don't know and failed to find the next steps

What is the recommended way to continue...Do I start by creating UML diagrams? or documents to list technologies and add business details about the business..
What should I name the files on Google drive(this may help)
Is there any course that helps in teaching this specific part?

I expect to have a list of missions to accomplish that include details about what must be done for the app to be created in the best practices

Comment: Sorry, there are too many questions here, and opinionated answers would constitute a book that may have been written after I figured it out in “hard mode”.

Comment: Indeed. What about starting reading this: https://opensource.guide/starting-a-project/ ?